# navigationController:willShowViewController: for ModalViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

`UINavigationController` has a delegate

```
navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
```

that gets called when a new view is about to be pushed on top of the `UINavigationController` stack. Do any similiar methods/delegates exist for `UIModalViewController`?

I am trying to implement the [iAdSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) for a view in the `UINavigationController` hierarchy (done) **and** a `ModalViewController`.

EDIT: Solution must be compatible with iOS4.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController has a method `presentViewController:animated:completion:` that allows you to specify a block that gets executed once the modal view controller is presented (it's not after the modal view controller returns, which is a common misconception). It's iOS5 only, however.

You may be able to do what you want in the completion block.

Comment: Thanks Brian, looking for an iOS4 compatible solution though. Updating my question...